# Wordpress form not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am familiar with PHP, HTML, CSS and can make a page that asks for information, then submits an HTML form to another page (or the current page) and then using PHP and the `$_POST` object, I can retrieve what the user entered and store it in a database. For example in pseudo code:

```
<?php 
    print_r($_POST); //I could put the post data in a database here...

?>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="" method="POST"><input type="text" name="data"></form>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can I do this if my site uses wordpress. I am dragging and dropping all of these things into my page, but I don't know how to go about creating a custom form that allows me to ask for some information and then store it in a database.

The tutorials on Plugins makes it appear that is the mechanism I have to use, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Create form like below and add it after body tag

```
   <?php
      if($_POST['submit']) {
            print_r($_POST);
      } else { ?>
        <form id="formid" action="" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="inputname" value="" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      <?php } ?>
```